# Update data in html table without refreshing whole page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am developing a simple project using spring and hibernate, and at the moment I need to update data in database and in html page without refreshing whole page. What ways can I accomplish this and what ways are best suited to the spring hibernate combination? Is it possible without using javascript?

Comment: Not possible without javascript. Create a JSON API that returns the data for the table, call that API using AJAX in the page, and maybe use a javascript data binding framework to update the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AJAX and JQuery most of the time and you cannot do it just using java or something like that. Javascript has come to stage if you need to perform some database operations without refreshing the page. If you want to learn more about how it can be done using spring and hibernate you may look at this link:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/ajax-with-spring-mvc-3-using.html

or

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/